# Uploading file with VPN...can they see my real ip?

Tags: vpn, anonymity

If I'm connected to a VPN, and I upload a file to a website from my computer via a system similar to this [image]

Can they tell that I have uploaded it from my
real IP or will they see my VPN IP?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Can they tell that I have uploaded it from my real IP or will they see my VPN IP?

Yes.

The connections should come from your VPN IP, if that type of traffic goes out across it.

They may also be able to tell your real IP if your browser runs their code and that code reveals other IPs.  As a single reference see http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/can-java-script-show-real-ip-address.223112/.

For a further remediation, try a [TAILS LiveCD](https://tails.boum.org/) - read all the warnings on that site, too.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the vpn is through tor